# Set same function to multiple objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects like this

```
var obj = [
  { name: "user", per: { pu: [{ end: "foo" }], ge: [{ end: "bar" }] } },
  { name: "user2", per: { pu: [{ end: "foo2" }], ge: [{ end: "bar2" }] } }
];
```

I want to add a new property `cond` which is a `function` to the objects in `pu` and `ge`, but when i do this, the function set to the only last object.

I loop through them then set them like so `obj[0].per[itm][0].cond = func` and that set to the last object only, but when i try to convert function `toString()` it set to all, `JSON.stringfy()` works as func same behavior.
Have I clone or set it in another way?

Comment: Please show us your attempt that is not working

Answer (score 0):

You may need to post fuller code as it's difficult to see where your error is.  However, considering it from scratch, I think some nested loops to match the nested arrays will get you there.

```
for (let o of obj) {
  for (let puObj of o.per.pu) {
    puObj.cond = func;
  }
  for (let geObj of o.per.ge) {
    geObj.cond = func;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below function...

```
const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
    return {
        ...oldObject,
        ...updatedProperties
    }
};
```

then you can pass in your new function or anything you need to add like this:

```
obj[index].per = updateObject(obj[index].per, {cond : function() {}} ); //use a loop to add the function to all objects in array
//check your current obj
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: the updateObject can come in very handy you can also use it to replace the value of a property on an object or add more property to it.